# Fill with three groups - how to center the third group and remove unused boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I avoid ggplot to make an emtpy boxplot in the case when I have only three groups? `ggplot(df, aes(group, value, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot()`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to know for sure without seeing the data but it seems like you have four groups as follows:

```
# Make 3 repetative groups
group <- rep(c("group_1","group_2","group_3"),n)
# Generate values for defined groups
value <- rnorm(length(group), mean = 5, sd = 1)
# Data frame with 1 more group with value
df <- data.frame(c("group_01", group), c(5, value))
colnames(df) <- c("group", "value")
ggplot(df, aes(group, value, fill = group)) + geom_boxplot()
```

From this simulated dataset we obtain boxplot as follows in [this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdyMQ.jpg), which seems to be your case.
You should check for levels in your data frame and remove the ones that are not necessary:

```
# Check for levels
levels(df$group)
# Remove unwanted group
df <- df[df$group != "group_01",]
# Plot the cleaned df
ggplot(df, aes(group, value, fill = group)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Now you acquire a graph with three groups.

[image: graph with three groups]